# SQLite for Universal App Platform won't load

Tags: c#, sqlite, sdk, uwp, windows-10-universal

I have a problem that SQLite for UAP won't load in my projects anymore... Is this because I have some sdk missing ? I've searched for the SQL-uap-.vsix sdk but I can't find this anywhere anymore so do I need to change my project so it works with a new update ? I can't find the solution...
[(Image)Reference missing and can't find SDK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7EeJ.png)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have probably updated the SDK, but still have references to the old version (3.10.0 in this case). Remove the references and re-add them, using the new version of the SDK.

Comment: Why do you need the UAP sdk? you already have the UWP sdk added.

Answer (score 0):

The extension is there (I did it not three hours ago..). Make sure you are searching online, its called "sqlite for universal windows platform".

Comment: Yeah I have that installed... It just won't do it for me :(

Comment: I would check the version as IInspectable mentioned in comments above, they recently released a new version.